# Converting Request QueryString to Decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, decimal

I can not convert query string to decimal.
In this example, when I control `Request.QueryString["Amount"]` value, It is `32.52` After the below code works, The `Amount` values is 3252M like that. How can I easily do this?

```
decimal Amount= 0;
if (Request.QueryString["Amount"] != null)
     Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["Amount"]);
```

Comment: Where is `Debt` involved in this? Are you really sure you want to use `decimal`?

Comment: Did you get `FormatException`?

Comment: Remember, the shorthand for making a literal numeric `decimal` is `1234m`. That's why you see the M at the end. I assume your current culture uses `.` for group separating (rather than decimal separating), and that's why `32.52` is turning into `3252m`.

Comment: @SonerGönül No, I did not. It converts the value 3252

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Convert.ToDecimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert.ToDecimal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses your current culture settings *by default*.

I *strongly* suspect your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) is not `.`, but [`NumberGroupSeparator` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `.`

That's why your program thinks this is a thousands separator, not decimal separator and it parses as a `3252`, not `32.52.`

As a solution you can use a culture which have `.` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` like [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or you can [`.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your current culture and set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` to `.` <sup>1</sup>

```
Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.QueryString["Amount"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
Amount = Convert.ToDecimal("32.52", culture);
```

1: <sub>If your current culture's thousands separator is not `.` already. Otherwise, you need to change it as well. Both property can't have the same values for any culture</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having problems with the Culture as stated in the rpevious answer. You may want to try using different cultures:

```
RetVal = decimal.Parse(Request.QueryString["Amount"], CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Then I would try:

```
RetVal = decimal.Parse(Request.QueryString["Amount"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The previous answer by Soner is more detailed.